# C++ Spin Image Resources

Tags: c++, image

Does anyone know of a good resource that will show me how to load an image with C++ and spin it?

What I mean by spin is to do an actual animation of the image rotating and not physically rotating the image and saving it.

If I am not clear on what I am asking, please ask for clarification before downvoting.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want platform independent solution?

Comment: I am using the windows platform. I know nothing of Mac or Linux. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org) and the extension [sdl_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image) and/or [sdl_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/)

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely default to OpenGL for this type of task, you can load the image into a Texture, then either redraw the image at different angles, or better yet you can just spin the 'camera' in the OpenGL engine. There are loads of OpenGL tutorials around, a quick google search will get you everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows using GDI+ you could show rotated image in the following way:

```
Graphics graphics( GetSafeHwnd() ); // initialize from window handle
// You can construct Image objects from a variety of 
// file types including BMP, ICON, GIF, JPEG, Exif, PNG, TIFF, WMF, and EMF.
Image image( L"someimage.bmp" );    

graphics.RotateTransform( 30.0f );  // 30 - angle, in degrees.
graphics.DrawImage( &image, 0, 0 );   // draw rotated image
```

You could read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533834%28VS.85%29.aspx) more detailed explanation.

---

Second solution is to use [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219740%28VS.85%29.aspx). You could create [texture from file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172801%28VS.85%29.aspx) and later [render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206154%28VS.85%29.aspx) it. It is not trivial solution, but it'll use hardware acceleration and will give you the best performance.

---

On Windows 7 there is available new API called [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370987%28VS.85%29.aspx). I have not used it yet, but it looks promising.

> Direct2D provides Win32 developers with the ability to perform 2-D graphics rendering tasks with superior performance and visual quality.

Comment: Is this fast enough to look animated?

Comment: It is fast enough if you'll use cached bitmap and double buffering.

Answer (score -1):

i agree with DeusAduro. **OpenGL** is a good way of doing this.

you can also do this with **Qt**

Comment: i dont know why someone downvote here, i did such a think in qt. i needed something like that in qt. anyway i suggested openGL. i think it is a strange behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

The "roll-your-own" solution is difficult.

I'd suggest looking into WPF - it might have some nice options in an image control.

Comment: Using WPF from C++ is awesome :)